# Reading FileMaker Pro fp7 files with Java

Tags: jdbc, filemaker

Someone exported FileMaker Pro 9 tables and I am trying to read them with Java.
I have the fmjdbc.jar installed I can register the driver with `Class.forName("com.filemaker.jdbc.Driver");`

The exported files are not on a server so the

```
DriverManager.getConnection(“jdbc:filemaker://192.168.1.1/mydatabase”,”username”, “password”)
```

example is not relevant.

How can I read standalone *.fp7 files on my windows drive with JDBC?

Answer (score 3):

The FileMaker files need to be hosted on FileMaker Server, which you then connect to with JDBC.

Comment: Thanks Sam, if I install a sever trail will i be able to import these exported fp7 files?

Comment: Your best bet might be to get a copy of FileMaker pro (not server), open the FileMaker files in FileMaker, and export the data you need as XML or CSV.

Answer (score 2):

Be aware that the com.filemaker.jdbc.Driver version is ONLY for use with FileMaker version 11 and above. Prior to that you need to use the SEQUELink driver - you should find it somewhere in the installer package for your version of FileMaker.

IIRC FileMaker Pro can be used as a JDBC host, however you need to make sure that the database file you are trying to access has the ODBC/JDBC extended privileges allowed (within FileMaker, open the file then choose Define->Accounts and create a privilege set that includes fmxdbc).